# Modelling stochastic solutions for the general stochastic epidemic

Tags: differential-equations

I have found the deterministic solutions for the following system of differential equations:

$$ 
s'(t) = -\beta s(t) i(t) \\
i'(t) = \beta s(t) i(t) -\gamma i(t)\\
r'(t) = \gamma i(t) 
$$

So the solution to the above differential equations hold when $n \rightarrow \infty$ but I want to model when $n$ is not $\rightarrow \infty$. I am using the general stochastic model with infectious periods following $I \sim exp(\gamma)$.

I understand the deterministic solution but how did the writer get the plot of $\bar{I}_n(t)$ where $\bar{I}_n(t) = I(t)/n$ ?

[image]

Comment: Without further information this question cannot be answered. There is not "the" stochastic solution!

Comment: It is where the infectious period follows an exponential distribution $I \sim exp(\gamma)$

Comment: There is still much too few information. Maybe you intend a Markov chain in countinuous time, but you have to elaborate this. In the context of Covid 19 there are many groups which try to model the epidemic and to evaluate them. So what is your model?

Comment: @DieterKadelka please look at my amended question.